# Sql-запрос с динамическим join'ом

Tags: mysql, join, sql

Есть 3 таблицы (*user, client, admin*).

user содержит поля *id* и *role*.
Поле *role* может принимать значение *client* или *admin*.

В таблицах *client* и *admin* есть поле *id*, которое ровно *user.id*, то есть имеет связь один-к-одному и собственные уникальные атрибуты (то есть у каждой таблицы свои поля).

**Пример**

Когда я делаю `select * from user where user.id=5`, я получаю только `role = client`.
А потом делаю запрос к таблице client для получения всей информации о клиенте.

**Есть 3 вопроса**

- Как сделать sql-запрос, чтобы обойтись одним запросом?
- Может, архитектура базы плохая, и нужно по-другому продумать, так как подобные запросы будут самые частые в системе. Если переделывать, то предложите вариант.
- Может, тут nosql будет практичней?

В голову пришла идея только с использованием left join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, тебе так подойдет:

```
SELECT user.id as userid, user.role as role, client.[какие нужно поля те ставишь] as [псевдонимы полей] 
    FROM user LEFT JOIN client on(user.id=client.id)
    WHERE user.role='client'

    UNION

    SELECT user.id as userid, user.role as role, admin.[какие нужно поля те ставишь] as [псевдонимы полей] 
    FROM user LEFT JOIN admin on (user.id=admin.id)
    WHERE user.role='admin'
```

Причем если в таблице client есть поле ХХХХ, а в таблице admin нет такого поля, то просто для объединия на его место ставишь NULL.

Пример:

```
SELECT user.id as userid, user.role as role, client.name as name, client.adress as adress,
null as isq
FROM user LEFT JOIN client on(user.id=client.id)
WHERE user.role='client'

UNION

SELECT user.id as userid, user.role as role, admin.name as name, null as adress, 
admin.isq as isq
FROM user LEFT JOIN admin on (user.id=admin.id)
WHERE user.role='admin'
```

То есть на выходе получаешь все записи с объединениями и всеми атрибутами, а по полю role уже определяешь, что перед тобой.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2198/5

Если только роль нужна, то как-то так.

Comment: Ну, вот как раз left join я и хотел избежать, с таким успехом быстрей будет склеить client и admin в таблице user. Пока других альтернатив не услышу, буду считать это рабочим вариантом.

Comment: Можно ещё вместо этого два вложенных select использовать.

Comment: И через if определять, какой вложенный запрос использовать?

Comment: По сути, это то же самое будет.

    select u.role from user as u 
    where 
    u.id in (select c.id from client as c where '1' = c.id) 
    or 
    u.id in (select a.id from admin as a where '1' = a.id)